# Insert statement not working for second table on same database in sqlite3 iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I have 2 tables on same database.

For first table data is inserted successfully using below code:

```
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

(sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0))==SQLITE_OK

   if ( sqlite3_exec(database, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"------- inserted here ----");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %s", error);

     if(sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0) ==SQLITE_OK){
           NSLog(@"-------data sucessfully inserted ");
      }
      else {
         NSLog(@"-------data insertion failed");
          sqlite3_exec(database, "ROLLBACK", 0, 0, 0);
      }

       (sqlite3_exec(database, "END TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0));
        sqlite3_close(database);


}
else {
   NSLog(@"-------sqlite open error ");
}
```

The data is inserted successfully as I log.

But when I use the same code for inserting into second table, no data is inserted I get log of

```
NSLog(@"-------data insertion failed")
```

I am also opening and closing database at each operation and releasing the handle.

I think sqlite is not allowing me to write on database but don't understand why? Since I have closed database with earlier operation.

Does anyone encountered same problem with no data insertion for 2nd table on same database file.

Addt note: there are no syntax errors and if I don't insert on 1st table then insertion is done on 2nd table which is weird.

Comment: check your query ? whether it is proper or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code,

```
-(NSString*) GetDatabasePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
        NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0] ;
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.sqlite"] ;
}

-(void)InsertPurchase 
{
        sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;
        NSString *path = [self GetDatabasePath];
        NSString *query;

        if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String],&db) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            query = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Your insert query"];

            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)
                        == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
}
```

Comment: i am using the same just additional transactions for faster execution, but my q is why my second table is not getting inserted for the same db? Even after closing end ending the transactions after first insertion? Moreover if i override first then second table works well, is it something to do with write issues within same db but in diff. table

Comment: i happen to replace my                                              ( sqlite3_exec(database, [insertStatement UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) == SQLITE_OK)  with your prepare statment and it works.       Thankx Krunal

Comment: accepting ans means click on the check mark which is on left side of my answer, when you click it will turn green. see here for e.g.:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work